# Getting the currently selection ContentControlListEntry in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I've had a look through the c# interop interface that allows you to add and select ContentControlListEntries but couldn't find a way to get the currently selected index/value, is there any way other than XML binding that this could be done?